# Ruby : SoftLayer API : getPendingEvents fails to show many relational properties

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to make a softlayer API call using Ruby to see upcoming maintenance and the machines that may be effected by the maintenance.  I have a few questions but I'm running into an issue seeing many of the relational properties documented here:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Notification_Occurrence_Event

Here is my simple program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => user, :api_key => api_key, :timeout => 99999999)

account = client['Account'].object_mask("mask[pendingEventCount]").getObject()
pending_event_count = account["pendingEventCount"]

current_time = Time.now.to_i

for i in 0..(pending_event_count/30.0).ceil - 1
  list_of_pending_events = client['Account'].result_limit(i*30,30).object_mask("mask[id, startDate, endDate, recoveryTime, subject, summary]").getPendingEvents
  for x in 0..list_of_pending_events.length - 1
    start_time = DateTime.parse(list_of_pending_events[x]['startDate']).to_time.to_i
    if start_time > current_time 
      pp list_of_pending_events[x]
    end
  end
end
```

The above works, but if I try to add a relational property to the mask, such as "impactedResources" it will fail saying that property does not belong to SoftLayer_Notification_Occurrence_Event.  Can someone help explain why this, and many other, relational properties are not valid in the above call?

Also, two quick other questions on this topic:

1) Why do some of the results in getPendingEvents have start AND end times in the past?  And why do some have a missing end time altogether?  Notice I'm checking if the start time is greater than the current time as there seems to be old maintenance data in the results.

2) Am I taking the right approach for getting upcoming maintenance and figuring out machines that will be impacted?  (Using getPendingEvents and then the 'impactedResources' property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and I added the "impactedResources" to the object mask and it worked fine. You may be getting the issue, because your API user does not have enough permissions, I recomend you try with the master user.

regarding to your other questions:

1.- When I ran your code I got only 3 events whose startDate is greater than the current time, so it worked fine for me. If you still are getting that issue you can try using objectFilters.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => user, :api_key => apikey, :timeout => 99999999)


object_filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new
object_filter.set_criteria_for_key_path('pendingEvents.startDate',           'operation' => 'greaterThanDate',
                                                                                  'options' => [{
                                                                                    'name' => 'date',
                                                                                    'value' => ['9/8/2016']
                                                                                  }])



list_of_pending_events = client['Account'].object_filter(object_filter).object_mask("mask[id, startDate, endDate, recoveryTime, subject, summary]").getPendingEvents
pp list_of_pending_events
```

2.- Yes, that approach wil work.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Nelson, as always.  Why would "pending" events show many events from the past?

Comment: I Guess softlayer wants to keep it for tracking, but you can use the object filters to only display the data you want